# SQL function throwing does not exist error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting the error listed below. The pavg type is suppose to keep a running average until the grp value changes/a.restart flag is set to True.

```
-- TABLE Stream
\echo -- creating table "Stream"

drop table if exists Stream;
create table Stream (
    id      int,
    grp     int,
    measure int,
    constraint streamPK
        primary key (id),
    constraint idNotNeg
        check (id >= 0),
    constraint grpNotNeg
        check (grp >= 0)
);

-- POPULATE: add some tuples to table Stream
\echo -- populating "Stream"

insert into Stream (id, grp, measure)
values
    ( 0, 0,  2),
    ( 1, 0,  3),
    ( 2, 1,  5),
    ( 3, 1,  7),
    ( 4, 1, 11),
    ( 5, 0, 13),
    ( 6, 0, 17),
    ( 7, 0, 19),
    ( 8, 0, 23),
    ( 9, 2, 29),
    (10, 2, 31),
    (11, 5, 37),
    (12, 3, 41),
    (13, 3, 43);


-- floatRec : a composite type that has an int and a boolean flag
\echo -- creating composite type "floatRec"

drop type if exists
    floatRec
    cascade;
create type floatRec as (
    number  float,
    restart boolean
);

-- floatRec: a composite type that has average and counter
drop type if exists
    pAvg
    cascade;
create type pAvgas (
    avg float,
    counter int
);


-- runningSum_state : accumulator function
\echo -- creating function "runningSum_state"

drop function if exists
    runningSum_state(pAvg, floatRec)
    cascade;
create function runningSum_state(pAvg, floatRec)
returns pAvg
language plpgsql
as $f$
    declare i alias for $1;
    declare a alias for $2;
    declare j int;
    begin
        if a.restart or i is null then
            j := a.number;
        elsif a.number is null then
            j := i;
        else
            j := a.number + i;
        end if;
        return j;
    end
$f$;


-- runningSum_final : returns the aggregate value
\echo -- creating function "runningSum_final"

drop function if exists
    runningSum_final(pAvg)
    cascade;
create function runningSum_final(pAvg)
returns floatRec
language sql
as $f$
    select cast(($1, false) as floatRec);
$f$;


-- runningSum : the aggregate function
\echo -- creating aggregate function "runningSum"

drop aggregate if exists
    runningSum(floatRec)
    cascade;
create aggregate runningSum(floatRec) (
    sfunc     = runningSum_state,
    stype     = pAvg,
    finalfunc = runningSum_final
);


-- pipeline sliging-window query that uses our agggregate function
\echo -- querying "Stream" with running sum

with
    -- look at the neighbour tuple to the left to fetch its grp value
    CellLeft (id, grp, measure, lft) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                measure,
                coalesce(
                    max(grp) over (
                        order by id
                        rows between
                        1 preceding
                            and
                        1 preceding ),
                    -1 )
        from Stream
    ),
    -- determine whether current tuple is start of a group
    CellStart(id, grp, measure, start) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                measure,
                cast(
                    case
                    when grp = lft then 0
                    else                1
                    end
                as boolean)
        from CellLeft
    ),
    -- bundle the measure and start-flag into an intRC
    CellFlag(id, grp, intRC) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                cast((measure, start) as floatRec)
        from CellStart
    ),
    -- call our runningSum aggregator
    CellRun(id, grp, measure, runningRC) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                (intRC).number,
                runningSum(intRC)
                    over (order by id)
        from CellFlag
    ),
    -- extract the running sum from the composite
    CellAggr(id, grp, measure, running) as (
        select  id,
                grp,
                measure,
                (runningRC).number
        from CellRun
    )
-- report
select id, grp, measure, running, average
from CellAggr
order by id;
```

**Error**

```
psql:runningAvg.sql:214: ERROR:  function runningsum_final(pAvg) does not exist
-- querying "Stream" with running sum
psql:runningAvg.sql:276: ERROR:  function runningsum(floatrec) does not exist
LINE 42:                 runningSum(intRC)
                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I am getting the error listed below. The pavg type is suppose to keep a running average until the grp value changes/a.restart flag is set to True.
I am getting the error listed below. The pavg type is suppose to keep a running average until the grp value changes/a.restart flag is set to True.

Comment: You are creating runnningSum_final and try to access runningsum_final

Comment: What @ClausBönnhoff said, but there's a typo.  Inconsistency with use of underscore.  Second (or third) set of eyes is always helpful.